# I bought a used iPod touch 5th gen on eBay, but it's connected to their iCloud!

Tags: icloud, ipod-touch, ios

Is there any way I can sign out without their password? They refuse to tell me (would you tell someone your iCloud password?), and I can't disable Find My iPod. I'm on the latest iOS (8.3). Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is nothing we can do for you. You can sign out anytime and make your new account (iCloud). The Seller must disable the Find myipad, it would be illegal for him to keep it since you have the proof of purchase. Ebay has good buyer protection.

Comment: If the seller won't cooperate, I would start a resolution process with eBay: http://resolutioncenter.ebay.com/

Comment: You likely purchased a stolen device if the seller is unwilling to help.

Comment: The seller must do this [they can do it without the device, from the web] - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351 If they will not, then register a complaint to eBay, as above.

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to the iPod, go to Settings -> iCloud and then press Sign out. I think that should work without having to enter any password. Then you can add your own or do whatever you want. 
If you don't have access to your iPod because they're locking it using Find my iPhone, there are either two ways
1. They tell you the password to access the device
2. You force your iPod to enter DFU/Recovery mode so you can restore it using iTunes.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -2):

You can delete the iCloud account without a password I think.

[Does this help?](http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-change-or-delete-icloud-account-on-iphone-ipad-ipod/)

Comment: Reading your link it doesn't take what happens when findmyiphone is turned on.